# User control with a client side API

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, rad

Maybe I've picked a totally inappropriate/bad example. 
What I have is a user control that contains a bunch of dynamically created Telerik RadGrids. 
My user control is added to a couple of Telerik RadPageViews that are part of a RadMultiPage that is used alongside a RadTabStrip. 
What I need to do is call a Javascript function in my usercontrol to update it's display whenever it's parent RadPageView is selected. 
So basically I have the following Javascript code:

```
function OnClientTabSelected(sender, args)
{
    // Get the MyControl that is on this tab
    var myControl = $find("whatever");

    // Call a method that updates the display
    myControl.doSomething();
}
```

Thanks,

David

Comment: Can you get clue from this question for your problem: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/radgrid-onselectedindexchange-to-update-radpageview.aspx

Comment: instead of using javascript to update the control may be you should try some other means such as ajax in the above link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a wrapper div in your User Control and then extend that div using jQuery to add your desired methods and properties.  The trick is to set the div's id='<%=this.ID%>' - that way the div has the same ID as the User Control (which is fine because the User Control doesn't actually render anything - only its contents).

Then back on your containing page, you can just reference your UserControl's ID using $get('whatever') - and you'll actually select your extended div.. which will have all your methods and properties on it.

The nice thing about this approach is that all of your methods and properties and neatly scoped and nothing is in the global namespace.

I have a full demo solution and details here if you want more info:
http://programmerramblings.blogspot.com/2011/07/clientside-api-for-aspnet-user-controls.html

Comment: That looks good. I'll definitely be checking it out in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a call to javascript method in input button if you are sure about the name of that function.

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="doSomething()" />
```

If you place any javascript code in the control that will be spit on the page and it will be available for calling provided both of them are in the same form.

for example your code will look like this if you look into the source of that page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function doSomething()
    {
      alert(new Date());
    }
</script>

<div>
  <span id="MyControl1_Label1">Dummy label</span>
</div>
<hr />
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="doSomething()" />
```

**Edit**: This is not a good way to access these methods in my opinion. When you are putting some javascript code inside a control then it should be used in that control only (There is no rule as such, its just a design suggestion). If you are trying to access javascript code of a control from outside that control then you need to revisit your design.

If you can give us more details on why you want to access that method, may be we can suggest some better way to do that.

**Update**: (As you have modified your question): Bit tricky to answer this as I dont have hands on experience with Rad controls. I guess there should be some feature which will help you to update the controls in that page without using javascript, may be have a look at clientside-API provided for Rad.

May be somebody who knows about RAD controls will help you.

Comment: Thanks very much for the sample code. But how would I go about calling doSomething using an instance of MyControl? 
ie: var x = <an instance of MyControl>; x.doSomething();

Comment: @dlarkin77: javascript method doesn't belong to any control as such, once your page is displayed in the browser it is part of that page, and there is no link between the control and javascript. If you place multiple instances of the same control in that page then that many times javascript code will be spit on the page but they are not linked to any instance after that.

Comment: I've edited my original question to (hopefully) give a better of what I'm trying to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the control method public

```
public void doSomething
```

and call this from the page

```
myControl1.doSomething();
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that doSomething is a Javascript method.

Comment: sorry, should have read the question better.  Can you post the code for your button click and doSomething method.

Comment: // button's click handler
function test()
{
            $find("<%= myControl1.ClientID %>").doSomething();
}

// MyControl's doSomething method
function doSomething()
    {
        alert(new Date());
    }